# Assign list of parent class reference with list of child class object does not work

Tags: c#, list

I am new to C#. 
I have a parent class declared:

```
class PmdTable
{
}
```

and I have  a child class

```
class PmdSdStageCfg : PmdTable
{
```

Now it complains if I do like:

```
List<OracleObject.PmdTable> instanceList = new List<PmdSdStageCfg>();
```

I get this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collection.Generics.List'.

Since PmdTable is the parent class. Why does this not work?

Comment: You need a co-variant collection. try: `IEnumerable<OracleObject.PmdTable> instanceList = new List<PmdSdStageCfg>();`.

Answer (score 3):

This does not work because `List<T>` is not covariant.

For details, see [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

If this were allowed to work, you would be able to do the completely invalid:

```
class OtherPmd : PmdTable {}

// NOTE: Non-working code below

// This will break, since it's actually a List<PmdSdStateCfg> 
// But it should be allowed, since instanceList is declared List<OracleObject.PmdTable> 
instanceList.Add(new OtherPmd());
```

Comment: Thank you for your talent answer.

Answer (score 1):

The technical answer is because List can't support covariance.

As you are new to C#, this may not mean much. It's a nasty side-effect of making collections work in a type-safe fashion. The upshot for you is that what you are writing won't compile, but the following will work just fine:

```
List<PmdTable> instanceList = new List<PmdTable>();
instanceList.Add(new PmdSdStageCfg());
```